# Assigning php value to title attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm try to add the return value of my php file to a title attribute. The correct data is return from the php file but for some reason 'appointmentData' is null. I have tried appointmentData.value and .innertext, but none of these work. ideas anyone? The value of appointmentData is "Id = 1 - Name = Blah"

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                appointmentData = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "getBookedAppointmentDetails.php?".concat(dataString));
        xmlhttp.send();

        $(this).attr('title', appointmentData);
```

I have edited my code to use the follow ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBookedAppointmentDetails.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (response){
                appointmentData = response;
                alert(appointmentData);
                $(this).prop('title', appointmentData);
            }
        });
```

I have inserted an alert to test the value of appointmentData, and this works fine. However, I'm till having problems assignment an attr/prop (tried both) to the element. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post exactly what the output of `appointmentData` looks like?

Comment: As you've jQuery loaded on page, use `$.ajax`. `var $this = $(this); $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'get....php', param: dataString, success: function(resp) {$this.attr('title', resp);}})`

Comment: `$(document).prop('title', appointmentData);` should help you..

Comment: The AJAX request run asynchronously, by moving the last statement in the `if` will work.

Comment: When I do this, xmlhttp.responseText becomes null.

Comment: @Tushar I've used your suggestion. but it won't assign the attribute to the element. any suggestions. $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "getBookedAppointmentDetails.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (response){
                    appointmentData = response;
                    $(this).attr('title', appointmentData);
                }
            });

Comment: @VIDesignz I have edited my answer to show this.

Comment: @CottonSocksBro I do not see the output. is `"Id = 1 - Name = Blah"` json?

Comment: The value of response = "Id = 1 - Name = Blah". When I alert response, this works, It won't assign to the element at an attribute.

Comment: @Tushar can you explain your comment e.g. var $this = $(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var appHover = $(this);

        var dataString = ("appDate=").concat(appDate).concat("&").concat("appTime=").concat(appTime).concat("&").concat("doctorId=").concat(doctorId);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBookedAppointmentDetails.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (response){
                appHover.attr('title', response);
            }
        });
```